# Regular Expression Extractor in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have this response in HTTP request as below

```
href="index.php?module=Meetings&action=DetailView&record=ed51c2d9-1958-bd61-cce1-509d30ccd4ac">
```

I want to get the value of "record", but when I set

```
Regular Expression : record=(.+?)
```

only "e" is returned. What do I need to do instead?

Answer (score 6):

Well the regular expression consumes as little as possible (due to the `?`). Hence, it is satisfied after taking in the first character. You should probably rather make it greedy and restrict the possible characters (so that it cannot go past the end of the parameter):

```
record=([a-f0-9-]+)
```

If you do not know which characters are allowed as the parameter's value, you could also say, consume everything but ampersands and quotes:

```
record=([^"'&]+)
```

Depending on where you use it, you might need to escape one of the quotes with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

The given text

```
href="index.php?module=Meetings&action=DetailView&record=ed51c2d9-1958-bd61-cce1-509d30ccd4ac">
```

Regular Expression to get the record values from the given text values

```
record=(.+)"
```

Regular Expression gets the following record values

```
record=ed51c2d9-1958-bd61-cce1-509d30ccd4ac"
```

Comment: Downvoted for being incorrect, unformatted (until another user fixed it), and two years late.  And this is just one of a dozen such posts you've made today.  This is not helping anyone, @Subash, least of all yourself.

Comment: This is the proper formats which i have verified and put here as post

Comment: The formatting was okay, it's your regex that's wrong.  You're assuming the `record` parameter will always be the last one listed, and that's not a safe assumption.

Comment: what is the needed results is user1813000 wants to get the result values in the following format so this might be right formats         user1813000 tried by this record=(.+?) regex but he got only record=e values instead user1813000 need whole values of records so my regex might be right